# Layered graphs with bubbles around graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Hello, I have a series of pictures that need to be drawn. The one above is the most complicated of them and I need it to be drawn in tikz. I think with this one I can adjust any picture to fit all the other ones. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: "I need it to be drawn in tikz", why? If you don't know TikZ, any drawing software could be used to do this and include the result as a graphic

Comment: *I think with this one I can adjust any picture* I don't think this is a right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of 2 ways of drawing such things in Ti*k*Z: multipart nodes or fit. I decided for the second method since you seem to be newcomer and this might be easier to understand and generalize.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,node distance=1mm]
\node[red] (B1) at (0,0) {B};
\node[below=of B1,outer sep=0pt,text width=10pt,blue] (B2) {00\\10};
\draw (B2.south east) -- ++(2pt,0) |- (B2.north east) coordinate[pos=0.25] (B2r)
(B2.south west) -- ++(-2pt,0) |- (B2.north west) coordinate[pos=0.25] (B2l);
\node[below=2mm of B2,outer sep=0pt,text width=15pt] (B3) {000\\100};
\draw (B3.south west) -- ++(-2pt,0) |- (B3.north west) coordinate[pos=0.25] (B3l);
\path (B2.south) -- (B3.north) coordinate[midway] (B23);
\draw ([xshift=-15pt]B23) -- ([xshift=15pt]B23);
\node[below=of B3,outer sep=0pt,text width=15pt] (B4) {110\\011};
\node[ellipse,draw,fit=(B1) (B4)] (B) {};
\draw[-latex] (B2l) to[out=170,in=190,looseness=3] node[midway,left] {0/0.5} (B3l);
%
\node[red] (D1) at (4,-0.6) {D};
\node[below=of D1,outer sep=0pt,text width=10pt,blue] (D2) {00};
\node[below=2mm of D2,outer sep=0pt,text width=15pt] (D3) {001\\101};
\draw (D3.south west) -- ++(-2pt,0) |- (D3.north west) coordinate[pos=0.25] (D2l);
\path (D2.south) -- (D3.north) coordinate[midway] (D23);
\draw ([xshift=-15pt]D23) -- ([xshift=15pt]D23);
\node[ellipse,draw,fit=(D1) (D3)] (D) {};
\draw[-latex] (B2r) to[out=10,in=190] node[midway,above=2pt,looseness=2] {1/0.5} (D2l) ;
\draw[-latex] (D2.west) to[out=190,in=10] node[midway,below=1pt] {1/1} (B4.-30) ;
%
\node[gray] (F1) at (-2.5,-3) {F};
\node[below=of F1,blue!50] (F2){111};
\node[ellipse,draw,fit=(F1) (F2)] (F) {};
\draw[-latex] (F.west) to[out=170,in=125,looseness=3] node[midway,left] {1/0.75} (F.north west);
\draw[-latex] (F2.east) -- (B4.160) node[pos=0.5,below=2pt] {0/0.25};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also did not spend too much time in tuning the appearance because typing in the numbers of your screenshot took too long. For the future, I'd kindly like to ask you to provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) such that others do not have to type in this stuff and also do not need to guess what you are familiar/comfortable with.